# Why this .htaccess with 1 variable won't work?

Tags: .htaccess, variables

I'm trying to get this but i really don't know why won't work. I try to change things and params and won't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} board=([0-9]+).0
RewriteRule ^forum/index\.php$ index.php?option=/$1? [R=301,L]

url:
www.abc.com/forum/index.php?board=13.0
```

Comment: Is that forward slash needed before $1?

Comment: In the RewriteCond, maybe add \ before the .0

Comment: You are passing nothing to index.php

Comment: @faa how do i pass board variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} board=([0-9]+)\.0
RewriteRule ^(forum/index\.php)/?$ index.php?option=/$1? [R=301,L]
```

That way the back reference $1 gets the group inside  `()` in the regex.

Modify accordingly with what should be inside the round brackets.

**UPDATE**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} board=([0-9]+)\.0
RewriteRule ^forum/index\.php/?$ index.php?option=/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Back reference %1 gets the group in the previous condition's Regex (Value of Board).

Comment: Seems like doesn't work either. still dont get my param board :(

Comment: i don't want to pass the path, just the board variable